# Can someone please translate this for me?

Tags: translation, simplified-characters

http://i.solidfiles.net/690a5c4a8c.jpg

I really need it as fast as I can, sorry if it's not appropiate to request translations like this, but it's for a relative of mine who really needs it. It's from an age preventing drug, I need to know what it contains, how should it be taken, etc. Thanks to anyone who'll try to help.

Comment: Its basic seem to be some chinese traditional medicines, can be used for recovering from fatigue, and should not be used for juveniles, and its shelf life is 24 months, and it's not a substitute of medicine(it's just a health care product). And see instruction for details of how to take it.

Comment: Totally offtopic. This website is not suitable for translations with no effort of your own, let alone 'urgent' translations. Try websites like reddit.com

Answer (score 1):

黄芪: the root of membranous milk vetch (Astragalus membranaceus)

刺五加: manyprickle (Acanthopanax senticosus)

山药: dioscorea [rhizome]; also called Chinese yam.

淫羊藿: epimedium

Need to see the instructions inside on how to take it.

Edit: says it also contains saponin and crude polysaccharide and it's not good for children.

Answer (score 1):

and not for children
(儿童不宜)    。

Answer (score 1):

dosage is not mentioned here. you should check a manual inside the box.

it's for against fatigue. not for children. it's not a replacement of medic.